# No such element when using compound classes Selenium

Tags: python, css, selenium-webdriver

I am working on web UI automation. I came across compound class. I googled and figured out a way to do it. But then I am facing No such Element exception. Kindly help.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element
 (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

Here is the snippet of html code I am working on to automate

```
<div id="prefill-two-up" class="two-up">
<div id="prefill-graduation-date" style="display: block;">
<!-- end grad date -->
<!-- begin hs date range -->
<div id="prefill-hs-date-range" style="display:none">
<!-- end hs date range -->
<p class="action-space">
<a class="btn action prefill-hs-done" data-hs-num="1" href="#">Done</a>
 or 
<a class="link-alt cancel-button-hs" data-hs-num="1" href="#">Cancel</a>
</p>
<div class="complete-form-error error" style="">
<span id="invalid-prefill-hs-form-open" class="message ui-state-error" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

I tried using CSS but failed.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p.action-space a.btn.action.prefill-hs-done").click()
```

Also Tried

```
 time.wait(10)
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.btn.action.prefill-hs-done").click()
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the exception details.